# How to fix "The openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS protection but is not available" error in Composer on Windows?

Tags: php, windows, curl, openssl, composer-php

I'm trying to run `composer install` on my Windows system, but I'm getting the following error message:

> "**The openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS protection but is not
> available. If you can not enable the openssl extension, you can
> disable this error, at your own risk, by setting the 'disable-tls'
> option to true.**"

**Here's what I've tried so far:**

- I've tried uncommenting the ;extension=openssl line in my php.ini
  file, but it didn't seem to enable the openssl extension.
- I've restarted my web server (Apache) after making changes to my
  php.ini file, but the error message still persists.
- Ran php --ini in the command line, which returned:

  ```
  Configuration File (php.ini) Path:
   Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
   Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
   Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
  ```

I've also tried running `composer config -g disable-tls true` but it doesn't solve the issue and I get the following error:

> "**You are running Composer with SSL/TLS protection disabled. Composer
> is operating significantly slower than normal because you do not have
> the PHP curl extension enabled. No composer.lock file present.
> Updating dependencies to latest instead of installing from lock file.
> See https://getcomposer.org/install for more information.**"

- How can I fix this issue and get `composer install` to work properly
  on my Windows machine?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Check whether you have installed `openssl` and `curl` PHP extensions (if not, installed **and** enable them)